# How to appeal against an unfair decision - conference paper

Tags: conference, rejection

My papers were rejected from a top conference venue in computer science due to laughably fallacious arguments. The reject decisions were based upon the following comments:

1. The one's complement checksum of an all zero bit sequence is zero!
2. O(n<sup>2</sup>) can be more efficient than O(n), because for n = 0.9, 0.9<sup>2</sup> < 0.9 !

What should I do now?

Comment: Note that, although comment 2 is expressed in a ludicrous way (we only care about positive integer n, and the smiley for crying out loud), there is a significant point there. A linear time algorithm is not necessarily faster than a quadratic time algorithm for inputs that we care about. For example, 10n^2 < 500n for all n < 50.

Comment: Firstly, O(0.9) is a meaningless notion. Although I agree with your point, O(n) represents an upper bound on the growth rate for big n.

Comment: Reducing the complexity is a fair contribution.

Comment: "O(0.9) is a meaningless notion" That's not correct. It's the same as O(1) [constant time algorithms].

Comment: Only O(1) represents a constant complexity. You can't put a number for n, big O denotes a growth rate.

Comment: @Christof You seem _extremely_ defensive about anything that you perceive to be a criticism of your work. I never said anything _at all_ about the quality of your contribution. I couldn't possibly say anything about the quality of your contribution because I have no idea what your paper says. All I said is that, in practice, a linear-time algorithm is not necessarily faster than a quadratic one. That is indisputably true. It is a point that one of your reviewers made. You should consider whether it is a relevant point, even though your reviewer said it in a ridiculous way.

Comment: @Christof Furthermore, the [call for papers](https://www.sigsac.org/ccs/CCS2016/call-for-papers/) says "Theoretical papers must make a convincing argument for the relevance of the results to secure systems." So, actually, reducing the complexity on its own doesn't seem to be a fair contribution to this particular conference unless you can argue that it's _practically_, as well as theoretically relevant.

Comment: Constant term is a fuzzy thing and depends on many factors, such as the programming code, hardware, etc. Following your comment, for some n, O(n^1000) can even perform much better than O(n). I'm not sure if any one compares big O notations for small n. Last but not least, for small n, we use other measures such as cpb, rather than big O to compare the performance.

Comment: "Only O(1) represents a constant complexity."  This is not correct.  While I can't think of a case where it's not appalling writing to use, O(0.9) means the growth rate of the function "0.9", that is, of the function constantly equal to 0.9, and so is the same as O(1).

Comment: Even if you believe that the reviewers are idiots, there is no appeal phase in most CS conferences once the decision is final. BTW this conference had a rebuttal phase, which already gave you a chance to state your claims. It did not work before. Just let it go.

Comment: 1. Christof, you are mistaken that $O(0.9)$ is not a thing that is permitted. It's perfectly allowed, it's just no one writes that way because it doesn't actually add any information more than $O(1)$. 2. The lack of knowledge of the constant factor in front is a major drawback of Big O notation.

Comment: For example, one can compare two direct methods for linear systems. One famous one is $O(n^3)$; a less famous one is $O(n^{\log_2(7)})$. It might seem that the latter is faster. But the former has a constant of $1/3$; the latter has a constant which is huge. This constant is so large that for any reasonable $n$, say $n$ small enough that $n^2$ double precision numbers will fit in 10 GB of memory, the first algorithm is still superior. Perhaps this could be reversed if, say, you were dealing with a matrix that takes 10 TB to be stored. But that's a problem for another decade.

Comment: In future, consider giving definitions of important concepts. E.g., if it is critical that 1-complement checksum of all zeroes is not zero, you could give the definition of 1-complement checksum in your paper to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @AlexeyB. That's good advice in general. However, in this case, the referee's comment is, almost literally, "But 1-0=0 !" No amount of definitions is going to stop that kind of mistake!

Comment: @David It is likely that this reviewer does not know or remember what this checksum is. I also do not know, and some legitimate readers may not know.

Comment: During my PhD I considered sending a complaint email to the programming committee after really bad reviews and unfair decision. My supervisor's response was: "The only thing that comes out of sending the PC chair a frustrated complaint email is bad reputation".

Comment: Perhaps (and probably not on this site) you could show the "code" where the reviewer's "error messages" were generated?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you need to do is to understand why your paper was rejected. I'm pretty sure your paper was *not* rejected from what you describe as "a top CS conference" for such obviously false reasons. Reviewers don't decide whether the paper is accepted or rejected: they advise the programme committee. The programme committee evaluates the reviews before coming to a decision and a review containing such obviously nonsensical comments will carry very little weight. If your paper was rejected because of the reviews, it was the other reviews, not this one.

Note also that, at top conferences, many papers are rejected simply due to bad luck. Usually, there are many papers that are a good enough quality to be accepted but the conference isn't big enough to take all of them. The actual reason for rejection may just be "We liked your paper and it's of essentially the same quality as papers we accepted, but there just wasn't room for yours and we liked these other ones just slightly more."

Comment: My paper was rejected from ACM CCS. And the review comment was only that one single line (plus some biased quantifiers), even after rebuttal.

Comment: @Christof The nonsense review was not the reason for rejection. You received other reviews, right? What did _they_ say?

Comment: I had only 2 reviewers, both nonsense, fallacious reasoning. I'm wondering why pc members couldn't note it. I know that this is a small community and I don't want to damage my reputation.

Comment: You believe your paper was rejected for reason X. It was not rejected for reason X. I suggest you discuss it with your advisor or with a colleague who's familiar with your paper.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is not the answer to my question. I'm wondering what the best act is In such instances.

Comment: The best act is to understand why your paper was rejected.

Comment: As a conference reviewer, I have seen co-reviewers do sloppy work. Very sloppy work.It's the job of the PC to keep quality control on that. If they do not do it, and let clearly inane reviews through on a systematic (occasional slips happen!) basis, it's not a good conference, or it's on the way of becoming one that's not good. Look for a better one.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you've already gone through the rebuttal process, so as far as I know, there's no further appeal. I'm going to focus on what seems like the core issue: what do you do if your paper is rejected for reasons that are utterly stupid?

1. Take a deep breath (or whatever your preferred calming action is). Rejection is a big part of being an academic; it's never pleasant, but learning how to handle it well is absolutely necessary to survive. That doesn't have to mean shrug it off; have a coping mechanism for handling rejection, and use it. (As an aside, I think it's something that doesn't get discussed enough when talking about career choices; I've known people who would have been fine researchers and teachers, but would have been destroyed by how much they had to deal with rejection.)
2. Take some time (a day or two, or a week) away from the issue to get some distance. During that time, feel free to be furious and vent (to appropriate audiences) about how stupid the reviewers and PC were.
3. When you're ready, come back to the reviews. Retread them carefully; it's quite easy when you're angry to misread a comment that gives important context as a vapid criticism. This time, read as charitably as possible. Consider that you might misunderstand something important; consider that they might have said something unclearly; consider that their comment is confused because they're confused about something in your paper.  Someone in your audience read your paper and had this response; they may well have misread your paper in a stupid way, but even so, that's something you need to fix, even if it seems blindingly obvious that they're wrong, because if one person had that misunderstanding, it's quite likely other readers too.
4. If you really can't make sense of the review, ask a colleague. Don't ask them "can you believe how dumb this review is?", ask, "I'm really not sure what this review is saying, could you give an outside perspective?"  If your colleague can't make sense of it either, then you can throw up your hands about it. The reviewer really did screw up, either by having stupid comments, or by writing them so unclearly that they can't be deciphered.
5. Revise, resubmit, and move on. Rejection is part of the lifestyle.

Comment: +1 for the second half of point 3 - this is vitally important and far too few people see it this way. Same thing for people writing furious rebuttals as letters to the editor explaining how the referee got it wrong: the clarifications need to go in the text of the paper, where they can prevent others in the audience from making the same mis-reading as the referee.

Comment: As a way to help the OP get some perspective on the problem, I recommend http://shitmyreviewerssay.tumblr.com/. After a few good laughs, you may be able to read the reviews of your paper with less emotion.

Answer (score 5):

First, Wrong decisions are made everywhere, everytime in the academia. Calm down.

Second, as far as I know about CS conferences, once a decision is made, there's no chance to appeal against a rejection. However, you may want to send your paper to another conference. Eventually it'll be accepted. Sometime, somewhere.

Comment: That is correct, but I feel I can't choke on it. the review comments are not only unconstructive but are also fallacious. This makes me a lot of doubts in the review system and the role of pc members.

Comment: Roll your eyes. Shake your head. Invent a not-so-nice designation of those reviewers. Then, move on, and find someone else who can appreciate your work more.